# Wordpress Menu Wrap

Tags: menu, navigation, wordpress

The following website's theme, `http://174.132.194.251/~taninew/`  is driving me crazy. I've always been able to use the css code for word wrapping and line wrapping in the past, but now it seems that my menu items wrap in two or even three lines.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make the menu items responsive, or just reduce width and padding on the menu list

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well I suggest you find someone who does!